# What information is stored in the materials file (.MTL)?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm in the development of a game engine, and am making heavy use of the Wavefront .obj files already, but now I'm getting into textures and materials, and so materials files have become relevant.

What details are included in the materials file and how is that information organized?

Comment: The .mtl format specification can be found online (http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/). For a shorter description you can also check the *Material template library* section in the Wikipedia article about the Wavefront .obj format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).

Comment: just so you know, blender cycles materials can't be imported into game engines, if I'm right.  I think it's because they use light bounce calculations, which are too slow for game engines.